Linked in Job search API - Developer Guide
I am trying to integrate the LinkedIn Jobs API into my application to allow users to search for jobs on LinkedIn. I need to request the r_JYMBII permission to access this feature, but I'm unable to find it and also i didn't get any other method to achieve this
I have already created a LinkedIn Developer application and have basic permissions like r_liteprofile and r_emailaddress. However, the r_JYMBII permission is not available in the products tab. I contacted LinkedIn support, but they directed me to StackOverflow for further assistance.
How can I request the r_JYMBII permission for the LinkedIn Jobs API OR There is any another way to implement linkdin job search api? Is there a specific process to follow, or do I need to contact LinkedIn through another channel?
